# Angular form validation using ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am using form validation using ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" property in my input field, that means that the validators works only when I am out of focus from my field, in this case if I have error I shows error text.

Is there a way in angular to remove this error when I am starting to edit my field again (onkeyup)?

Comment: Not without custom code as the ngModelController for that element will still be marked as invalid.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will create a custom code that will handle the validation and error fields.

Comment: You could use this module http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/ which sorts out the visual representation of validation errors then create a directive that clears the invalid styling of the element (using the module) when the user focuses in.  I'd be happy to help you with this if you choose to use the module :-)